# Omit branches from the tf tree

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, robot-state-publisher, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

using a URDF, the robot_state_publisher constructs the tf tree which is published in the relative topic. Is there any way to choose which branches of the tf tree are being published without modifying the URDF? For example using some argument in the launch file from where we invoke the robot_state_publisher which specifies that some transformations won't be published? Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327979/omit-branches-from-the-tf-tree/) by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any way to choose which branches of the tf tree are being published without modifying the URDF? For example using some argument in the launch file from where we invoke the robot_state_publisher which specifies that some transformations won't be published?

No, there is no support for this.

Or at least: not in the standard (ie: "official") `robot_state_publisher` node.

Everything in the urdf stored in the `robot_description` parameter will be considered by the `robot_state_publisher`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:
It would perhaps be good if you could describe *why* you want to do this (just so we avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info)).

A possible work-around could be to have multiple `robot_description` parameters, each containing only a subtree and multiple `robot_state_publisher`s that are responsible for processing only those parts.

**Comment by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on 2019-07-09**:
I am trying to connect two tf trees constructed by two different URDFs. However both URDFs build a frame named "base_link". So when the second tf tree is constructed, the robot_state_publisher finds the "base_link" frame from the first tree and therefore does not construct its own. Hence, I would like to omit the "base_link" frame of the first tf tree and construct only the second one.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:
It might actually be possible to instead of avoiding publishing certain transforms, they can be removed after the fact by using [tf_remapper_cpp](http://wiki.ros.org/tf_remapper_cpp).

But again: it would be best to first know why you want to do this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:\

> Hence, I would like to omit the "base_link" frame of the first tf tree and construct only the second one.

so just the `base_link` frame or everything starting with `base_link`? The "branches" you refer to in your question suggests the latter, but your explanation makes it sound like you'd like to do the former.

> I am trying to connect two tf trees constructed by two different URDFs.

are these really urdfs, or `.xacro`s? In the latter case: `xacro` supports composition, which, with a suitable prefix on all `link`s and `joint`s, would be the normal way to do this. If it's really `.urdf`, then that would not be possible.

Additionally: is the current contents of `robot_description` the union of the "two different urdfs" (ie: without actually merging the structures)? Because that is not necessarily supported.

**Comment by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on 2019-07-09**:
The files are not xacros. Sorry about the misunderstanding, I want omit only the "base_link" frame, not the whole branch.